# integrated scene builder in intelij idea size problem

Tags: javafx, ide, scenebuilder

Hello stackoverflow communuity , im  working on java fx project in intelij idea , i heard the intelij idea had the option to add scene builder to the interface of the ide but i was not happy of the result the integrated of scene builder in intelij idea is awfal and so big that i can't design my interface in a fast and easy way like the original scene builder and i also can't use another ide because it's the teacher obligation to work like that if you can help to reduce the scene builder interface's size  (button , links .....)
thanks  a lot[image]

Comment: Are you not able to use the standalone Scene Builder app?

Comment: Unless you're supposed do some coding with some tutor/teacher involved, how is the teacher supposed to check, which progam you used to edit the fxml or even the .java files? Furthermore the controls in the integrated scenebuilder seems pretty similar to the standard scenebuilder. It's only the center viewport that seems to be smaller because of the limited space available. Perhaps IntelIJ supports different views and you could close the projects down by default for some view you use to edit fxmls?